# Django FileResponse - How to speed up file download

Tags: django, performance, download, google-drive-api

I have a setup that lets users download files that are stored in the DB as `BYTEA` data.  Everything works OK, except the download speed is very slow...it seems to download in 33KB chunks, one chunk per second.

Is there a setting I can specify to speed this up?

**views.py**

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def getFileResponse(filedata, filename, filesize, contenttype):
    response = FileResponse(filedata, content_type=contenttype)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
    response['Content-Length'] = filesize
    return response

return getFileResponse(
    filedata = myfile.filedata, # Binary data from DB
    filename = myfile.filename + myfile.fileextension, 
    filesize = myfile.filesize, 
    contenttype = myfile.filetype
)
```

Previously, I had the binary data returned as an HttpResponse and it downloaded like a normal file, with normal speeds.  This worked fine locally, but when I pushed to Heroku, it wouldn't download the file -- instead displaying `<Memory at XXX>` in the download file.

And another side issue...when I include a text file with non-ASCII data (i.e. á), I get an error as well:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters...: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I handle files with Unicode data?

### Update

Anyone know why the download speed gets so slow when changing from HTTPResponse to FileResponse?  Or alternatively, why the HTTPResponse to return a file doesn't work on Heroku?

### Update - Google Drive

I re-worked my application and hooked it up with a Google Drive back-end for serving files.  It employs `BytesIO()` suggested by Eric below:

```py
def download_file(self, fileid, mimetype=None):

  # Get binary file data
  request = self.get_file(fileid=fileid, mediaflag=True)
            
  stream = io.BytesIO()
  downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(stream, request)
  done = False

  # Retry if we received HTTPError
  for retry in range(0, 5):
    try:
      while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

      return stream.getvalue()

    except (HTTPError) as error:
      return ('API error: {}. Try # {} failed.'.format(error.response, retry))
```

Comment: Note to self: try `content.encode("utf-8")` -- https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/86007/django.http.FileResponse

Answer (score 3):

I think the difference you observe between HttpResponse vs. FileResponse is caused by the spec: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#buffering-and-streaming

In your previous code, an HttpResponse was created with one huge byte string containing your whole file, and the first iteration pass returned the complete response body.  With a a FileResponse, the file is iterated in chunks (of 4kb, 8kb or other depending on your WSGI app server), which (I think) are streamed immediately upstream (to the reverse proxy then client), which may add overhead (more communication over process boundaries?).

It would help to know the app server used (uwsgi, gunicorn, waitress, other) and its relevant config.  Also more details about the heroku error in case that can be solved!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This was a while ago, so I don't remember all the specifics, but I think it was using gunicorn (whatever is the default web server for a Heroku-Django app).  I don't remember seeing any error messages on Heroku, the downloaded file was just a file with the text "<Memory at XXX>"

Comment: Ah I know!  FileResponse wants a file object, not bytes. You would have to wrap myfile.filedata in a BytesIO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'll check it out.

Comment: I re-worked the old code to download files from Google Drive instead and I did end up using BytesIO like you suggested.  See updated answer above.  You put me on the right path, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

why you store whole file in database.

best case is to store file on hard and store only path on database

then according to your web server you can let web server to serve file.

web services serve file better than Django.

if files have no access check store them on media

if your files have access control you according to your web server you can use some response headers

if you use Nginx must use X-Accel-Redirect and use any alternative on other web services tutorial on https://wellfire.co/learn/nginx-django-x-accel-redirects/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For now, I'm looking for a DB-storage solution.

Comment: In general, when there is no useful processing to do at the Django level, it makes sense to avoid going DB → Django → app server → reverse proxy / load balancer.



If you have reasons to use django to implement the storage, login, permissions, etc. a technique is to write the data in a real file, then use the appropriate method to hand off real data transfer to your frontend server (X-Sendfile, X-Accel, etc.).  This doesn’t apply to Heroku, which really doesn’t want to serve static files and doesn’t provide sendfile accelerator.

Comment: For completeness: the «classic» Heroku way is to store files in a storage service (AWS S3, Digital Ocean Spaces, etc.), use your Django app for login, permissions, etc. and instead of returning file data from Django, return a download URL (generated with an API call to the storage service, to get a link with a signature and expiration).